# How to update one column of table with another column table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `available_quantity` column in `mobiles` table and available quantity is 2.
And I have `quantity` in `stock` table. This quantity is 7.

Now what is the SQL command for updating the `available_quantity` column? Means after updating `available_quantity` have to show 9.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The question does not have enough information for an answer.

Comment: Did you try anything. Search for `Update with Join` in google you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can use MERGE statement for updating table from another table,

```
MERGE INTO mobiles_table M
USING stock_table S
    ON (M.primary_key_column = S.primary_key_column)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
M.quantity = M.quantity+S.quantity;
```

Edit appropriate table and column names in the query